# WebLogic 12.1.3 error WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, weblogic, cdi, weblogic12c

WebLogic 12.1.3 fails when deploying a web application with a simple CDI injection. The following exception is thrown:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Interface2] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject public pruebas1.Clase1.clase2]  
  at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)  
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)  
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)  
  at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)  
  at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)  
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace  
Caused By: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Interface2] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject public pruebas1.Clase1.clase2]  
  at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:315)  
  at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284)  
  at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionTarget(Validator.java:342)  
  at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetValidator.addInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetValidator.java:29)  
  at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.createInjectionTarget(BeanManagerImpl.java:943)  
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace  
>
```

When i deploy the war in WebLogic 12.1.3 (Zip Distribution and Installers for Developers) inside OEPE 12.1.3.2 i get the error described. But, whith WebLogic 12.1.1 (Zip Distribution and Installers for Developers) inside the same OEPE 12.1.3.2 there is no problem. Neither there isn't problem if i export thye war file and deploy with the web console without OEPE integration. Additionally, when i deploy the war in WebLogic 12.1.3. standalone ("full" release) there is no problem.

I encountered too, that the MANIFEST.MF file (inside wlserver/server/lib/api.jar) references "javax.inject_1.jar" that doesn't exist in wlserver/modules folder. Instead there is the file "javax.inject-1.jar". To make my project working (import the class javax.inject.Inject class) i copied a file named javax.inject_1.jar from the javax.inject-1.jar file in the same folder.

The war java source structure is:

```
src  
    pruebas1  
        Clase1.java  
    pruebas2  
        Clase2.java  
        Interface2.java
```

The war WebContent structure is:

```
WebContent  
   WEB-INF  
       beans.xml  
       weblogix.xml
```

Classes and interface:

```
@WebService  
public class Clase1 {  
  @Inject  
  public Interface2 clase2;  
  @WebMethod  
  public String aMayusculas(@WebParam(name = "palabra") String palabra) {  
     long tm = System.currentTimeMillis();  
     System.out.println(tm + " - clase2: " + (clase2 == null ? "null" : clase2.toString()));  
     return palabra == null ? "null" : tm + " - " + palabra.toUpperCase();  
  }  
}

public interface Interface2 {  
  void doIt(String a);  
}

public class Clase2 implements Interface2 {  
  @Override  
  public void doIt(String a) {  
     System.out.println(a);  
  }  
}
```

XML files:
beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="  
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">  
</beans>
```

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">  
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>  
    <wls:context-root>prueba05weblogic</wls:context-root>  
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Thanks in advance.

Efren V.

Comment: This is more or less a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162522/deployment-error-weld-001408-with-wls12c-and-oepe This also mentions that is was fixed in a patch to 12.1.1 http://biemond.blogspot.com/2012_01_01_archive.html Maybe it's broke again in 12.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved.

I created a SR in Oracle support site. Oracle built an internal patch.

Efren.

Answer (score 1):

After three days searching, we found that the project only worked if deployed through the weblogic console, if we deployed through oracle plugin in eclipse it wont work.

So, if you are using eclipse, in the "servers" view, right click weblogic server, click "Properties -> Weblogic -> Publishing", change the radio "Pubish as a virtual application" to "Publish as  exploded archive"

Answer (score -1):

you can replace @Inject annotation with @Produces as workaround